# What is guest except in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is the code in my Laravel `auth/LoginController`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

I am new to Laravel. My question is `$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');` what does this code line means? what except method do?

what is the prupose of this line `$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#controller-middleware read the docs it will make things clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first `$this->middleware()` inside the constructor is telling Laravel that you want to protect some/all of your methods from being accessed.

```
$this->middleware('guest');
```

Here 'guest' is one of the middlewares.
This means that if the user is not Authenticated, all the methods within this `LoginController` can be accessed.

However, sometimes you want to configure this maybe you want to only apply the middleware for a method or exclude this middleware for a method, that's when `except` and `only` come into the picture.

```
->except('logout')
```

This means exclude the `logout` method.

```
$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
```

So this means that `guest` can enter all the methods within this controller but not the `logout` method.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means to neglect logout method if the user is not logged in.